# Securing Sinatra and Rails in Same Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, sidekiq

I have a rails app that has devise and a full user experience. But there is also a sidekiq worker and the admin for that is in sinatra. I dont mind that but I do want to secure it. My config/routes has the sidekiq route - but how can I secure? I should also mention this is on heroku as well. Ideally i would like to simplify with an htaccess but that really isnt an option

Answer (score 0):

Umm .. guess i should have RTFM'ed a bit deeper..

If anyone else stumbles upon this. The docs are pretty clear on a sop for this.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring